# the source of the report definition has not been specified windows forms application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, rdlc

I'm trying to display report in **reportviewer** i'm using the following code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataSet ds = GetData();
            ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("Power7000_ICCard_Prepayment_System.Form_RpttotalMonthConsumptionReport.rdlc", ds.Tables[0]);
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
            reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        }
```

```
private DataSet GetData()
        {
            
            string Query = @"select tmc.customer_id,toc.Customer_name,toc.meterNo, tmc.date, tmc.consumption from public_month_consumption_record tmc
                                INNER JOIN public_openaccount1 toc ON tmc.customer_id = toc.Customer_id
                                where MONTH(tmc.date) = '" + SelectedMonth + "' AND YEAR(tmc.date) = '" + SelectedYear + "';";

            dt = DLL_Common.SysGlobal.DataBaseAccess.GetDataTable(Query);
            

            decrypted_dt = dt;

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                decrypted_dt.Rows[i][0] = DLL_Business.DatabaseEncryption.GetDecrypt(dt.Rows[i][0].ToString().Trim());
                decrypted_dt.Rows[i][1] = DLL_Business.DatabaseEncryption.GetDecrypt(dt.Rows[i][1].ToString().Trim());
                decrypted_dt.Rows[i][2] = DLL_Business.DatabaseEncryption.GetDecrypt(dt.Rows[i][2].ToString().Trim());
                decrypted_dt.Rows[i][3] = dt.Rows[i][3] ;
                decrypted_dt.Rows[i][4] = dt.Rows[i][4];
            }

            DataTable dtCopy = decrypted_dt.Copy();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.Tables.Add(dtCopy);
            return ds;
        }
```

but the **reportviewer** error :

> the source of the report definition has not been specified

Comment: after adding the datasource to reportviewer plaease use reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Power7000_ICCard_Prepayment_System.Form_RpttotalMonthConsumptionReport.rdlc";

Comment: **ReportViewer Exception**: A data source Instance has not supplied for the data source _**DataSourceName**_

Comment: After Changing Data Source "[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332611/a-data-source-instance-has-not-been-supplied-for-the-data-sourceproduct-detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332611/a-data-source-instance-has-not-been-supplied-for-the-data-sourceproduct-detail)"
After Checking This Link
Thanks For Your Help

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the report path.

```
reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "";
```

Here is the stack overflow link

[The source of the report definition has not been specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903170/the-source-of-the-report-definition-has-not-been-specified)

Comment: to be like that ?
`reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"Power7000_ICCard System\Form_Rpt\totalMonthConsumptionReport.rdlc";`

Comment: Can you please check the link which I provided. Which gives you more understanding rather than I explain it here. If you still get issue we can take a look.

Comment: not yet is just try to understand what's the different between 

`report[0] = new ReportParameter("MyName", "Raha");`
`
var reportDataSource1 = new ReportDataSource { Name = "WpfApplication17_User", Value = _users };
`